# permission for per column in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

i have faced some problem. So, I have a table. There are 20 columns in this table. I want to give permission (can add, can edit, can view) for per field and for every user. I did something like that.

My table (Which is contains 20 columns)

1. Id
2. Name
3. Region
4. Country
5. PeopleCount
6. CityId

...... (Fields are example)

User table

1. Id,
2. Name

......

**Note:** My table columns name are In this table

ColumnNames Table

1. Id
2. Name

Action

1. Id
2. Name (can add, can edit... )

AssosiationBetweenUserMyTableAction

1. UserId
2. ColumnNamesId
3. ActionId

When I add a new user I want to be able to give permission user for every column (field)
For ex.

How can i do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code how you have tried ?

Comment: @BasantaMatia I am thinking about it

Comment: Check my bellow suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add *Can add* or *Can edit* field in your table.

What you can do is, when an user click on edit button, just show the fields those can be edit and rest make **disabled** in your html control, so that user can't change them.

But yes, if you want to give permission to specific user for add,edit or view, then I would suggest to use **Role Based**. Create a **Permission table**. Keep some meta or default record, like Add, Edit, View, Delete etc. Then create a map table for **Role** and **Permission** table. For example **RolePermissionMapping** table. So when you are adding a **new user** just pass the permission here. For that, you need to create 3 checkbox for Add, Edit, View in your view. And add these 3 fields in your model too. Then in your controller method you can insert these data in your RolePermissionMapping table.

So, now, just validate the user permission before you render your data in your html code.

For example,

```
//In your Razor code
@if(Model.IsEdit)
  {
   //show your edit button else hide that 
  }
```

Then while user click on the edit button, just show those fields that you want to update, rest you can disable them.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks your answer but i have to do it for every field not table]

Comment: That's what I already mentioned in my answer, show the fields those can be edit (for example name,Region,Country etc) and rest make disabled (for example Id) in your html control, so that user can't change them